# TypeScript - Propertie includes a class

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, having two class as show under:

Oferta.ts:

```
module Ofertas{
   export class Oferta {
      VMVivienda: Ofertas.Vivienda();

      constructor(){
         this.VMVivienda = new Ofertas.Vivienda();
      }
   }
}
```

Vivienda.ts

```
module Ofertas{
   export class Vivienda {
      viviendaID: number;

      constructor(){
         this.viviendaID = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

When compiling, the console throws the error:

> error TS0294: The property 'Vivienda' does not exist on value of type
>   'typeof Ofertas'

Comment: is this a typo in your question `VMVivienda: Ofertas.Vivienda();`. It should be `VMVivienda: Ofertas.Vivienda;` Even with fixing that line i do not get the error when compiling

Comment: The compiler returns the same error. It's weird, intellisense doesn't show any error....

Comment: You don't necessarily need to prefix Vivienda with Ofertas. It(Oferta) should already be in that namespace. I don't know if it will fix the error but your code will be more compact. I don't know what causes the error except the typo @Jehof mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `/// <reference path='vivienda.ts' />` to oferta.ts